# Changing memSQL default aggregator port when running memSQL via docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port, singlestore

I am trying to use MemSQL via docker container. 
Below is my Docker-compose.yml entry for the memsql docker

```
memsql:
image: memsql/quickstart
volumes:
  - "./jenkins/jenkins_memsql_schema.sql:/schema.sql"
ports:
  - "3307:3306"
  - "9000:9000"
hostname: memsql
container_name: memsql
```

The default port that memsql runs on is 3306. I would like to change this default port.

When I raise this container and try to change the port from within the container. 
I use the following command:

```
memsql-ops memsql-update-config --key=port --value=3307
```

I get the following error:

```
You cannot change the port variable for an existing MemSQL node.
```

So:

1. It seems you cannot change the port once memSQL is running, so how do you change it before?
2. How can this be set via the docker-compose setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of MemSQL running in Docker, the easiest way is to leave MemSQL running on port 3306 within the docker container, but have a different host port map to that port.

In a non-Docker install you can choose the port to install MemSQL on during installation (--port option to https://docs.memsql.com/memsql-tools-reference/latest/create-node/). It is also possible to change the port of a node by removing and re-adding it with the desired port - memsql-update-config cannot be used for this.

Comment: The problem with this is that docker-to-docker communication happens within the internal docker network. So those requests wont go through the 'host' machine and thus through the port I want. Since I have memSQL and mySQL both running on 3306 in this internal network there is a conflict. Thats why I need to change memSQL. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Replied on https://www.memsql.com/forum/t/changing-default-memsql-port-when-using-docker-compose/425. Copying here:

The setup.sh file has

`memsql-ops memsql-deploy --role master --developer-edition $DEPLOY_EXTRA_FLAGS`
`memsql-ops memsql-deploy --role leaf --developer-edition --port 3307 $DEPLOY_EXTRA_FLAGS`

You can change the port there - e.g. add --port 4567 to the deploy master command.

Answer (score 0):

**1. It seems you cannot change the port once memSQL is running, so how do you change it before?**

I would suggest that you start from [here](https://github.com/memsql/memsql-docker-quickstart), which means you can start by modifying the installation script which called `setup.sh` and then modify Dockerfile to expose the desired port instead of 3306 which will makes you able to have the correct ports when you start the container

**2. How can this be set via the docker-compose setup?**

If all it takes to change it is to run this command or maybe extra simple steps:

```
memsql-ops memsql-update-config --key=port --value=3307
```

You can pass the port as an environment variable through docker-compose.yml using [environment](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) key and add the above command to the script called `memsql-entrypoint.sh` to be something like this:

```
if [ ! -z "$CUSTOM_PORT" ]; then
    memsql-ops memsql-update-config --key=port --value=$CUSTOM_PORT
fi
```

> In both cases you will need a customized Dockerfile and use `memsql/quickstart` as a base image.